# Поясните за проектирование и оформление кода

Tags: php, архитектура, проектирование, code-style

О себе: кодер на пхп, делаю разные парсилки, чекалки, в т.ч. с капчей, обходом разного рода защит.

Мне очень не нравится стиль, как я пишу код. Например, задача - многопоточно соединяться с разными хостами, используя при этом прокси, для каждого хоста собственное (учитывая что прокси может сдохнуть), затем парсить результат, и зависимо от него, передавать выполнение дальнейшим блокам кода: парсить следующую страницу, поставить на ожидание ввода капчи и т.д. При этом должен быть интервал в 10 секунд между запросами к одному хосту, причем когда один хост ожидает, выполняется другая работа.

Раньше я делал такие конвееры многократными структурами if/elseif/else, switch/case, goto, чтобы выполнение кода циклически перебрасывалось из одного блока в другой. Столкнулся с большой сложностью - читабельность и понимаемость кода из-за многократной вложенности конструкций, сложность отладки, избыточное количество переменных, в которых запутываешься. В итоге кодинг превращается в настоящую головоломку, и каждый новый проект вызывает FFFFUUUUU-реакцию, когда приходится это снова повторять.

Сейчас занялся очередным таким проектом, и понимаю, что я неправильно делаю, и можно проще, независимо от уровня сложности, просто я не знаю как. Подскажите, что я не так делаю, и как делать правильно?

Comment: Попробуйте думать в терминах сущностей, которые «работают» у вас в программе. Одним словом, ООП (только не «ключевое слово `class`», а «мышление в терминах действующих лиц»).

Comment: Лол, что не так с вопросом? Хоть бы уточнили.

Comment: @kanaris, самое лучшее - устроиться на работу или стажировку джуниором в компанию, в подмастерья к опытному программисту. Его повадки вы переймете быстро, узнаете много нового и полезного. Работая над своими проектами, которые по определению может потянуть один человек, вы не научитесь писать код так, как вы хотите, судя по вопросу.

Answer (score 6):

*Мини-ремарка:*

> Лол, что не так с вопросом? Хоть бы уточнили

Вы не поверите, но описанные в вопросе проблемы, с которыми вы столкнулись, и есть та огромная разница между хорошим опытным программистом и новичком. Каким вы себе представляете ответ на такой "не маленький" вопрос? :)

*Теперь попытка краткого ответа:*

- Правильно ставьте задачу. Это действительно половина ответа.
- Производите декомпозицию, т.е. разбиение задачи на небольшие
  подзадачи. Меньше задача - меньше переменных в голове, яснее цель,
  проще и короче решение, меньше число вариантов решения, проще
  сосредоточиться и/или переключить контекст в голове, если что-то вас
  отвлекло.
- Думайте не в терминах языка программирования (if+else, do+while и
  т.д.), а в терминах той области, в которой вы решаете задачу. Не в
  терминах типов хранения/представления данных (int, string и т.д.), а
  в терминах объектов, фигурирующих в текущей области знания. Не вы
  "перемещаете" и "изменяете" данные, а объекты как бы сами живут и
  меняются, исполняя некоторые обязательства, взаимодействуют друг с
  другом.
- Отнеситесь серьезно к форматированию и организации кода. Более того,
  правильно примененная декомпозиция задачи не оставит вам шансов
  писать процедуры/функции/методы, которые не умещаются по высоте на
  одной странице монитора.
- Но позаботьтесь так же об адекватном именовании абсолютно всего. Код
  должен быть таким, чтобы практически любые комментарии были излишни
  (кроме достаточно глобальных, являющихся документацией к
  классу/модулю, или очень специфических). Найдите середину между
  одно-двухбуквенными названиями переменных и
  оченьДлиннымиНазваниямиКоторыеЧитатьУжеНуСовсемНеудобно.
- Помните, что многопоточку дебажить в принципе сложно. Поэтому очень
  важно максимально устранить в коде остальной "дискомфорт".

**Upd**. Шаблонов и концепций придумано много - по формулировке задачи не очевидно, что лучше подойдет (да и я не эксперт, если честно).
Я бы старался максимально избегать многопоточки (не асинхронности) - очень часто профит от ускорения не перекрывает затрат на сложность разработки и поддержки.

В простейшем случае, вы разбиваете вашу задачу на независимые этапы, для каждого из которых реализуется свой обработчик. Позаботьтесь о том, чтобы обращение к общим данным было потокобезопасным и его было как можно меньше - чем более независимым будет обработчик каждого этапа, тем меньшей головной болью будет одновременный запуск нескольких обработчиков. Обозначьте зависимости и требуемые входные данные для каждого типа обработчиков, а также данные на выходе.
После этого достаточно лишь организовать механизм сохранения состояния и общения между обработчиками соседних этапов (т.е. переход от этапа к следующему) - это могут быть очереди, шины, сокеты, обычные колбэки событий и т.п. Подумайте над тем, кто будет инициировать переход между состояниями (push-based, pull-based, centralized).
На русском гуглить наверное будет очень сложно (у меня сходу довольно скудные результаты получились). Теги: multithreading pattern, asynchronous pattern, event-driven programming, task-based asynchronous pattern, [немного](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20434919/1094048) про разницу между асинхронностью и многопоточностью.

Comment: > Каким вы себе представляете ответ на такой "не маленький" вопрос? :)
Ну как-то так: "то что ты делаешь, это называется шаблон бла-бла-бла. Вот мануал (линк), вот (еще линк) так продвинутые люди решают твою задачу. Схема уже давно откатана и не надо изобретать велосипед".

Comment: @kanaris добавил небольшое пояснение. Возможно чуть лучше прояснит ситуацию